# Arrow unicode character doesn't display on phone

Tags: html, mobile, unicode, character, symbols

I'm trying to create left and right button for a div using "&#10092" and "&#10093" character. I'ts showing fine on desktop but on phone i get just a black square  not the arrow .It's there a way to make it display on phones ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the phone having a font which contains this character. As it seems to be somewhat obscure, the phone probably doesn't have it. Either for space-conservation reasons, or because nobody has bothered creating a phone-optimised font which contains it.

If you want to ensure a particular character is visible on all clients, you'll need to embed a web font with the appropriate character. That also gives you more control over its appearance.